# ionic serve does not render in browser

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a project I have checked out into 2 different folders. I was trying to help someone else get the project running, and when it kept failing, I thought I would retry in another folder - and I while I can run `ionic serve` - the web page starts but the page is blank and I suspect there is some script running for a long time.

Versions:

- ionic: 2.1.0
- cordova: 6.3.1
- npm: 3.10.3
- node: 6.7.0

I have run `npm install` to install all dependencies on both folders. There is no difference in the content of these folders - they are checked out from the same repo and are on the same branch!

**EDIT**

I have attached the console from the unsuccessful run below:
[image: Failed run console]

and from the successful run:
[image: Successful run console]

The package.json is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "author": "...",
    "homepage": "...",
    "private": true,
    "config": {
        "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "copy": "ionic-app-scripts copy",
        "i18n": "node ./scripts/i18n.js",

        "serve:before": "watch",
        "emulate:before": "build",
        "deploy:before": "build",
        "build:before": "build",
        "run:before": "build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ionic/storage": "^1.0.3",
        "ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
        "ionic-native": "^2.0.3",
        "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
        "moment": "^2.14.1",
        "ng2-translate": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^0.0.23",
        "i18next-conv": "^3.0.3",
        "typescript": "^2.0.3"
    },
    "description": "...",
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

Comment: any kind of errors in console?

Comment: nothing - it's just hanging there

Comment: then i suggest you to debug for error which is quitting your app execution

Comment: Could you provide your package.json file?

Comment: I have added the package.json file in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to [this](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/how-to-set-up-ionic-app) web site:

> Before starting, please make sure you have a stable internet connection so that node installs all the modules needed.
>
> First, create a directory to download the app source code in, then run:
>
> 1. npm install -g ionic
> 2. npm install -g cordova

If I did this in the source folder right after checking out, I didn't have the issue any more.